# Spring data Neo4j : org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException:

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am getting the following exception while accessing my graph using Spring Data Neo4j:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: '__type__' on http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/125; nested exception is org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' on http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/125] with root cause
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' on http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/125
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestEntity.getProperty(RestEntity.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:26)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.createEntityFromState(Neo4jTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(GraphBackedEntityIterableWrapper.java:27)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper$MyIteratorWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(IterableWrapper.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:353)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:370)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:269)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:244)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:294)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.save(AbstractGraphRepository.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:329)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.save(Unknown Source)
```

My Nodes and relationships look like this :

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @GraphId 
    Long nodeId;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    Long uid;

    String name;

    @RelatedTo(type="FRIENDS", direction=Direction.BOTH)
    Set<User> friends;

    @RelatedToVia(type="FRIENDS", elementClass=IsFriends.class)
    Set<IsFriends> friendRelationships;

    @RelatedTo(type="LIKES", direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
    Set<Article> article;

    @RelatedToVia(type="LIKES", elementClass=Reco.class)
    Set<Likes> likeRelationships;

    //getters and setters

    ..
    ..

}
```

From here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/aFZCp5T3ABo

I do understand that there is some problem in defining both the RelatedTo and RelatedToVia fields in the NodeEntity class. As defined in the User class, the User has relationships with other Users by a @RelationshipEntity named FRIENDS and the user has relationships with other Articles (@NodeEntity) by a @RelationshipEntity named LIKES.

What is it that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: was your relationship perhaps not created with SDN? If you want to read it it has to have the correct type information.

Comment: Michael, As far as I know it has been created thru SDN. But you think my design looks good ? Is it ok to have the RelatedTo and RelatedToVia annotation fields defined the way I have done ? Thanks for your help Michael.